# Find outliers in a list of coordinates data

Tags: geolocation, geocoding

I have a list of coordinates for a boundary line, it looks like this:

```
-74.71224,31.11124
-74.70204,31.71901
-74.71414,31.77729
-74.70109,31.74797
-74.49712,31.74914
-74.70144,31.71014
-74.49714,31.49251
-74.70915,31.49724
-74.71194,31.70104
-74.77215,31.71404
-74.77312,31.71092
-74.71137,31.72254
-74.14272,31.71177
-74.14943,31.72044
-74.14515,31.72794
-74.19794,31.72114
-74.91112,31.71751
-74.94971,31.70549
-74.94172,31.70943
-74.97931,31.49104
```

The entire list should gives you a closed-loop boundary line.

And for my data, there's some points that shouldn't be there, i.e. a point that's not part of the boundary line.

And my question is, how can I find these points?

EDIT:

My idea is that, right now I have a circle with some points away from that circle, how can I check every points if it's too far away from that circle to be consider part of it?

Please see picture for what I mean. I think if a points's distance from its closest one's is bigger than x, then it's an outliers.

[image: Two points are outliers]

**points in the file are not in order, meaning, not one next to next other in terms of location on the map**

Comment: I _think_ you'll need some other set of data to compare with...because who's to say that the point shouldn't be there...maybe you WANT a circle, but it looks like a pacman...without stating "should be circular", there's no reason to think pacman is wrong...or, maybe instead of shape, a max distance between points? or something comparable?

Comment: Is this tracking data? might each update also have a timestamp? you might be able to use that to find odd points (ie: this point is 10 miles away, and happened 1 second after the prior point...discard)

Comment: I edited my op try to be more clear. I think if a points's distance from its closest one's is bigger than x, then it's an outliers. Thanks.

Comment: No this is not a tracking data, just a big kml file I got and I just want to make sure it doesn't has any outliers before I use it.